# How to parse date string which is formed by the CRT function?

Tags: c++, c, windows, locale, crt

I'm working on a Windows-driven C++ project now. And there is a function which composes a file names with date portion in them. It uses the [wcsftime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strftime-wcsftime-strftime-l-wcsftime-l?view=msvc-160s://) C runtime library function to format the date portion with the `"%x"` formating code. This code corresponds to the

> %x    Date representation for the locale

as the documentation says.

Now, I need to check which files match to some dates-range. So, I need to parse this date portion of the file name back to the date and perform the comparing. But, I'm in trouble: how to do this? I didn't find any CRT function which can do the work. Furthermore, it could be much more better for me to get the formating string alike the "dd-mm-yyyy" for the current locale in order to parse this string. But I didn't find any way how to do this.

I pay your attention, that it's about the CRT functions. Its locale differs from the locale used by the [GetLocaleInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfow), for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution is to go *forward* : Generate a filename using the same pattern, but for a test date of `2001-02-03`. The result will tell you the order of year,month and day.

Comment: Actually, I decided to go this way...

Answer (score 1):

The big question is, if you know the locale with which the date in the string was created.

If you are on the same machine then you can use the ***time_get*** function described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_get/date_order).

With that you can get the order of the day, month, year in the date. Having that you can then first build a `std::regex` to extract the digits and then assign the digits into the corresponding date segments.

A regex could look like R"(\d{1,4}[.\/,;]\d{1,4}[.\/,;]\d{1,4})" which will match 3 digit groups separated by some typical date separators.

Then, with the know how of the date order, you can extract day, month and year from a string.

Some example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iomanip>

// Example for year/month/day formated string
std::string fileName{"file7_234x2021/5/23abc.txt"};
std::regex re{R"((\d+)[\.\\\/\,\;](\d{1,4})[\.\\\/\,\;](\d{1,4}))"};


int main() {
    
    std::smatch sm{};
    
    if (std::regex_search(fileName,sm,re)) {
        
            int year = std::stoi(sm[1]);
            int month = std::stoi(sm[2]);
            int day = std::stoi(sm[3]);
            
            std::cout << std::right << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << day << '-' << std::setw(2) << month 
            << '-'<< std::setw(4) << year << '\n';
    }
}
```

If you do not know the date order, then you may have a big problem and can only find out with some heuristic methods what is what.

E.g.

- Numbers above 31 are years
- Numbers above 12 are days (or years)

But, somehow error prone . . .

Comment: " on the same machine " -> "using the same `std::locale`". There's a reason `do_date_order()` is `virtual`; these things can vary even within one program.

Comment: Yes. Correct. Makes things even worse . . .